# Missing /media/cms/css/debug.css

Tags: joomla-4.x

While using browser developer tools I noticed an error in my joomla 4 site:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://[server]/media/cms/css/debug.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

I think the issue is that /media/cms/css/debug.css doesn't exist, and the server is returning a 404 page.

This reference to /media/cms/css/debug.css is in the head of index.php. Is that reference supposed to be there, and the file really is missing? Or is that reference not supposed to be there, and therefore it's fine that the file is missing?

Comment: There's a file /media/cms/css/debug.css in my joomla 3.10 instance, but not in any of my joomla 4 instances. Instead it's in /media/system/css/debug.css. The files are pretty much identical, so clearly the Joomla team redefined in v4 where it should be stored. Are you using a 3rd party template on your joomla instance? If so, it might be something the template developers missed when upgrading it to Joomla 4. You could try doing a search through your .php files looking for "debug.css" - that might identify the source file which is causing the issue.